# How would I create multiple objects of the same instance

Tags: java

So basically, what I want to do is create many objects from the same instance.
I don't mean creating a new instance like this:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

I mean to have multiple objects from that 1 instance.

So for an example:

```
//Long way that causes more lag
Object obj = new Object();
Object obj2 = new Object();
Object obj3 = new Object();

//causes less lag
Object[] = <all the instances of obj>

long way
#####
##### //# = block | each # has its own instance

short way
#####
##### //# = block | each # is controlled by ONE instance
```

I can't really think of any examples of this but I think Minecraft uses this for all of the blocks.

The reason why I want to know how to do this is because I think it will reduce lag.

If there is a way / is not a way please tell me.

Comment: An object and an instance refers to the same. You can have multiple references to the same instance of a class.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. An object and an instance of a class are the same thing. Maybe what you have in mind is the flyweight pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Comment: Are you taking about singletons ?

Comment: Or do you need static methods?

Comment: Are you refering to reusing object instances? In this case, you would simply create an object once and then replace its inner member fields every time you wanted to reset it. Note that you need a mutable object for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). It is a technique that allows sharing of object data among many similar objects, greatly reducing memory requirements. I'm not familiar with Minecraft internals, but I strongly suspect that they use this (or something very similar) for their blocks. It is typically used when:

- Many similar objects are used and the storage cost is high
- The majority of each object's state data can be made extrinsic
- A few shared objects would easily replace many unshared objects
- The identity of each object does not matter

In addition to the Wikipedia article linked above, take a look at [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-flyweight) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Object and Object instances mean the same. If you would like to create multiple objects or mulriple instances, same thing, you need to call new as an array allocation, e.g.

```
Object[] obj = new Object[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have "different objects of the same instance" because objects and instances are the same thing. Like "humans" and "people", more or less.

However, you can have many **references** to the same instance, which may be helpful in keeping down memory footprint and creation/copy time in appropriate situations. Note that in Java, a variable defined with an object type, like, say:

```
String str;
```

Is not actually holding an object. It is holding **a reference to an object**. So you can have something like:

```
String originalString = "This in a string".

String a = originalString;
String b = originalString;
String[] arr = new String[10];
for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    arr[i] = originalString;
}
```

In this case, you will have **only one object**. Every variable in this code example - `originalString`, `a`, `b`, and all the elements of `arr` - are all references to the same object/instance.

[image: The result is this]

Comment: This is the exact opposite thing I wanted to do. I wanted origional to equal a and b.

Comment: @Minegeek360 and that's the case, since a, b and originalString are 3 references to a unique String instance: "This in a string". So `a == b` and `a == originalString`.